# Cell Expansion is not happening while exporting jasper reports to XLS format

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have an ireport with static fields and text fields.The database consists of large part of data and for single row in a database there is multiple line data.So when i am exporting the jasper report through java code to PDF format it is stretching and elaborating and printing the entire data without any missing of lines but when i am exporting to XLS it is missing the data and moreover stretching of the cell is not happening.I will show an image for better understanding.[image]

As you can see in the above the data is printing very clearly in PDF.
[image]

In the above,that is XLS format data is hiding or in the sense missing.So my question is how to display the entire data in a cell when reports are exported to XLS format.I am posting java code below.

```
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
    String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/report5.jrxml");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("sql",sql);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport (jasperReport,map,conn); 
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    //String result = JasperRunManager.runReportToHtmlFile("./usertemplates/test.jasper" , parameters, conn); 



    JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(xlsReport));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setWhitePageBackground(true);
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.setFontSizeFixEnabled(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
    //System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+xlsReport.size()); 
    //bytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();
    String fileName = "InvoiceReport.xls";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
+ fileName);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(xlsReport.size()); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    //xlsReport.close(); 
    //System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    xlsReport.writeTo(outputStream); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    //outputStream.close(); 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();} 

        %>
```

and the jrxml code is below.

report5.jrxml

```
<detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="13" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="24b49d3f-5c78-4a19-a4d2-e2cbff95a40d">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{serial number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="13" y="0" width="242" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4332ae75-6371-4879-b805-9d07254f0784">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DescriptionOfGoods}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="0" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="54828e8d-bae0-4669-873e-36de8bf54446">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PerUnitPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="0" width="64" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e02408a1-2bcd-4fb9-94d3-ed0c0c1d8ff6">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nos]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="459" y="0" width="96" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="00ba44d4-b287-4a29-8bf3-1ad07da760e8">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Quantity} *$F{PerUnitPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="255" y="0" width="54" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d74b9bd4-9608-44a7-b46e-55f39ed0c852">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Comment: I put these two in <reportElement> but its not working.<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are using `deprecated` method in jasper report, consider to update your code:

```
JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
xporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(xlsReport));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setWhitePageBackground(true);
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
\\... set all your configuration like above
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

You need to set the properties on the `reportElement`'s in `textField`'s containing the text the need to bit fit.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
```

If this is not working as desired your solutions are:

1. Make excel change font size (to fit)

   ```
   configuration.setFontSizeFixEnabled(true)
   ```

> Flag for decreasing font size so that texts fit into the specified cell height.

2. Set manually the column width in excel

`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width`, property with an integer value measured in pixels

If your still not happy turn to [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi), load the workbook and modify it as you like....

Comment: I have done what you said but its still the same.not expanding the cell.You can see the code above which is edited

Comment: What happend in excel?, any changes?

Comment: No. In PDF format it is expanding as you can see above and in XLS format some is printing and some is hiding

Comment: I can not reproduce your example, normally you don't even need the properties it will stretch by it self (if not enough setFontSizeFixEnabled fix it).. I you like and can give you one of my test jrxml to see if you have same problem. I also see you are using deprecated methods for font, but I don't think is directly related.